# Django Admin - How to Put Icons in front of Model Names

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm in Django 1.6 and I'd like to alter the admin to show an icon in from of each model name (on the admin's index page).

The problem is I can't alter the template (As far as I know) because I'm creating a third party installable app, and when users install it, presumably they could already have their own styles, and customizations for their admin page.  (correct me I'm wrong).

So far I've tried doing this in models.py but it's still escaping the HTML on the admin page:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class DataConnection(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = mark_safe("<img src="..." />My Model")
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this seems to work.  I monkey patch the admin.site.index and admin.site.app_index methods with my modified versions that grab the response objects and add in the desired HTML and mark it as safe:

```
def index(self, *args, **kwargs):
    response = admin.site.__class__.index(self, *args, **kwargs)
    my_app_context = [d for d in response.context_data['app_list'] if d.get('app_label','') == u'my_app_name']
    if my_app_context:
        for m in my_app_context[0]['models']:
            m['name'] = mark_safe(("<img src='...' /> " + unicode(m['name']))
    return response
admin.site.index = index.__get__(admin.site, admin.site.__class__)

#...Do something similar for the admin.site.app_index method
```